# Pixel Flow Library for Processing

Tags: java, processing, libraries

I downloaded the pixel flow library for processing. I'm familiar with processing and thought it would be pretty straight forward understanding the mechanics of the library and syntax. However, I've been finding it really difficult to understand. does anyone know how one should go about understanding the mechanics of libraries specifically Pixel Flow if you have info on that, general info is also welcomed.

Link to library: https://github.com/diwi/PixelFlow

Comment: Please try to show some work that you have done, and try to find a more specific example of where it is you are having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** You need to be familiar with how classes and objects work. If you aren't comfortable with that, then take some time to learn about [using objects](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/using-objects) and [creating classes](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes).

**Step 2:** Read through the documentation. I'd start [here](http://thomasdiewald.com/processing/libraries/pixelflow/). Read the reference for every function, and read every example. You aren't trying to memorize anything, just get a general idea for what the library can do.

**Step 3:** Get a simple Hello World program working. What's the simplest thing you can do with the library? Do that. Go back to the reference as often as you need.

**Step 4:** Iterate on that Hello World program. What's the next thing you can do with the library? Work in **small steps** instead of trying to do everything at once.

**Step 5:** Then when you get stuck, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific technical question, and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on libraries in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries).

Comment: Thank you very much! this is greatly appreciated!